# Can a rogue planet neither orbit around a star nor a galaxy?

Tags: rogue-planet

As we know, rogue planets don't orbit around a star, how about galaxy? Can a rouge planet not orbit around a galaxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They would be enormously difficult to observe, but with a big enough [gravitational assist](http://www.universetoday.com/121961/how-do-stars-go-rogue/) a rogue planet certainly could be ejected from a galaxy and become a "double rogue" so to speak, or intergalactic rogue planet is probably a better term.  Rogue (or intergalactic) stars have been observed.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intergalactic_star) and [Here](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2014/11/rogue-stars-outside-galaxies-may-be-everywhere).  The same gravitational forces that create intergalactic stars absolutely should create inter-galactic rogue planets and in fairly significant numbers.  The merging of 2 galaxies should create millions of them.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why it couldn't, though the chances of it happening are small. There are hyper velocity stars that are not gravitationally bound to the Milkyway, if a planet is ripped away from its star due to a close encounter with another star or black hole it could be given enough velocity to reach a galaxies escape velocity (about 537 km/s).